# awk and grep for existence

Tags: awk, grep

I have a text file that have strings enclosed within double-quotes. I want to extract these strings and check another file to see if they exist or not. Right now, I got as far as:

```
awk -F'"' '{print $2}' ~/test | <GREP COMMAND>
```

How do I go through the extracted strings in a sort of a loop with my grep command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have GNU grep;

```
grep -f - file
```

If not, you could print out a `sed` script from awk, or maybe create a slightly more complicated awk script. Or just join the output into one big `egrep` expression;

```
egrep "$(awk -F'"' '{ printf ("%s%s", j, $2); j="|" }' input)"
```

Comment: This solution was pretty cool too. Way more efficient than the spawn-a-grep-each-time.

Comment: In the printf command, why did j come before $2? I tested it out with $2 first and the my first and second strings were not pipe-delimited. I don't seem to see why $2 should not be first.

Comment: Also one other question, how does one surround the 'awk result with another string. Say I wanted to match against title="<STRING>" where <STRING> is the pipe-delimited result from "$(awk -F'"' '{ printf ("%s%s", j, $2); j="|" }' input)"

Comment: @syker Insert it in the awk output: `$(awk -F'"' '{ printf ("%stitle=\"%s\"", j, $2); j="|" }' input)`

Comment: Right, although it would be more efficient to only have `title=` once, like `egrep 'title=(a|b|c)'` rather than `egrep 'title=a|title=b|title=c)'`. You can factor that outside the `awk` script, like `egrep 'title=('"$(awk ...)"')' file`.

Comment: As for the initial value if `j`; this is a common idiom for building a list like `a|b|c`. You start with an empty joiner, so when you append the joiner before the current value `a`, you get simply `a`. Then we set the joiner to `|`, so on the next iteration, we get `|b`, and then `|c`. You don't want `'|a|b|c'` because the empty first element matches every possible input string.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [xargs](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?xargs), which reads lines from standard input and runs a given command once for each line. It'll depend on what version of xargs you have installed, but I would start with something like this:

```
awk -F'"' '{print $2}' ~/test | xargs -I % grep % <file>
```

The `-I %` flag tells it to replace `%` with the argument read from stdin, instead of appending it to the end of the commandline, which is the default.

Comment: This is fairly inefficient; it will spawn one `grep` for each search phrase.

Comment: Thanks this worked well for me:

 awk -F'"' '{print $2}' ~/test | xargs -I % grep 'name=\"%\"' file

Answer (score 1):

Unquote the strings and pipe to grep as a pattern file:

```
tr -d '"' < strings.txt | grep --file=- another_file.txt
```

(Note that this will not behave correctly with escaped `"` characters, but your awk command wouldn't either, so I assume it's not a problem.)

If applicable, using `--fixed-strings` with grep also will speed things up.

Comment: Ageee that `tr -d '"'` is way superior if removing leading and trailing double-quotes is all you needed `awk` for.